# can't cut/Paste or move file in all my partition even using "sudo nautilus"

Tags: nautilus, copy, paste, cut-command

I have big problem to use my PC because I can't cut or paste or move all my file and folder in all my partition without system partition of Ubuntu.
I use Ubuntu 17.04.
I tried to search any response and I tried to open from terminal "sudo nautilus" but even on that way, I've still the same problem.
Please help. Thanks